# PHP native validation error using the select dropdown list

Tags: php, html, css

Hi i am making a small site that has four select drop down list. What i did is im using it to target the form itself. Meaining like this

```
<?php 
   <form action="" method="post">
     //code here...
   </form>
?>
```

My problem is i want to validate my select dropdown list the four of them , if you did not select at the dropdown list, all the four of them it should validate Please Fill at least one, then if you choose only one select dropdown list then it goes to true; how wil i get this? hmm quite confuse .. Here is my code below

```
<?php include("template/header.php");?>
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);?>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>COMMON WORDS IN FDC</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <?php require_once("script/connect.php");?>
      <?php
        $error = "";
        $one = "";
        $test = "";
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
          if($_POST['kuan'] || $_POST['kanang'] || $_POST['basta'] || $_POST['ahh']){
            if(empty($_POST['0'])){
              $error = 'Please Fill';
            }
          }else{
            $test = 'success';
          }
        }
      ?>
      <form action="" method="post">
          <div style="text-align:center; font-size:15px;">
           <?php
              echo $error;
              echo $test;
            ?>
          </div>
          <br />
          <table class="table font">
             <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>KUAN</th>
                <th>KANANG</th>
                <th>BASTA</th>
                <th>AHH</th>
              </tr>
             <tr>
              <td>

                <?php
                  if(isset($_GET['Macky']) == 1){
                    echo "Macky";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='kuan'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kanang'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='basta'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='ahh'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' class='btn btn-success' />
                            </td>
                          </tr>";

                  }elseif(isset($_GET['Richmond']) == 2){
                    echo "Richmond";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kuan'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kanang'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='basta'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='ahh'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' class='btn btn-success' />
                            </td>
                          </tr>";
                  }elseif(isset($_GET['Jeff']) == 3){
                    echo "Jeff";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='kuan'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kanang'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='basta'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='ahh'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' class='btn btn-success' />
                            </td>
                          </tr>";
                  }elseif(isset($_GET['Yongski']) == 4){
                    echo "Yongski";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='kuan'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kanang'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='basta'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='ahh'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' class='btn btn-success' />
                            </td>
                          </tr>";
                  }elseif(isset($_GET['Michael']) == 5){
                    echo "Michael";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kuan'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kanang'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='basta'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='ahh'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' class='btn btn-success' />
                            </td>
                          </tr>";

                  }elseif(isset($_GET['Tere']) == 6){
                    echo "Tere";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kuan'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kanang'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='basta'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='ahh'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' class='btn btn-success' />
                            </td>
                          </tr>";

                  }elseif(isset($_GET['Jane']) == 7){
                    echo "Jane";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kuan'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kanang'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='basta'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='ahh'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' class='btn btn-success' />
                            </td>
                          </tr>";
                  }elseif(isset($_GET['MsPinky']) == 8){
                    echo "Ms.Pinky";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='kuan'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kanang'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='basta'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='ahh'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' class='btn btn-success' />
                            </td>
                          </tr>";
                  }elseif(isset($_GET['Rd']) == 9){
                    echo "Rd";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kuan'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kanang'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='basta'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='ahh'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' class='btn btn-success' />
                            </td>
                          </tr>";

                  }elseif(isset($_GET['Pat']) == 10){
                    echo "Pat";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='kuan'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kanang'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='basta'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='ahh'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' class='btn btn-success' />
                            </td>
                          </tr>";
                  }elseif(isset($_GET['Len']) == 11){
                    echo "Len";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kuan'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kanang'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='basta'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='ahh'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' class='btn btn-success' />
                            </td>
                          </tr>";
                  }elseif(isset($_GET['Roxanne']) == 12){
                    echo "Roxanne";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='kuan'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                     echo "<td>
                            <select name='kanang'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='basta'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                            <select name='ahh'>
                              <option name='0'>--Please Select--</option>
                              <option name='1'>1</option>
                              <option name='2'>2</option>
                              <option name='3'>3</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>";
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' class='btn btn-success' />
                            </td>
                          </tr>";
                  }
                ?>
              </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
       <a href="index.php" title="back to list">Back to List</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone help me with this?
need badly help

Comment: Why you write <option name='0'? Why you use name it should be value. like <option value='1'>1</option>

Comment: i use name to pass the value ...

Comment: The `name` attribute should only be on the `select` element. The `option` element should have a `value` attribute unless you want it to use whatever is in between the `option` tags.

Comment: oh i see then how will be able to do that?

Comment: Whew, pretty long source for such a task. [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_Repeat_Yourself)

Answer (score 0):

First, as the comments suggestion, use "value" and not "name" in your options. Second, I understand that only one of them should be required, so this changes things. Finally, this code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      if($_POST['kuan'] || $_POST['kanang'] || $_POST['basta'] || $_POST['ahh']){
        if(empty($_POST['0'])){
          $error = 'Please Fill';
        }
      }else{
        $test = 'success';
      }
    }
```

Should work like this:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      if($_POST['kuan'] == 0 && $_POST['kanang'] == 0 && $_POST['basta'] == 0 && $_POST['ahh'] == 0){
        $error = 'Please Fill';
      }else{
        $test = 'success';
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Where is your form action? Use form `action="page.php"` where page.php is the current page.

Comment: thats ok im using to target it to the form itself... its the same